ovs-vsctl stucks and seems there's no schema when using ovsdb in cluster mode
#!/bin/sh

ovsdb-tool create-cluster /host/var/lib/openvswitch/conf.db /usr/share/openvswitch/vswitch.ovsschema tcp:0.0.0.0:6632 2> /dev/null

ovsdb-server \
   --unixctl=/host/var/run/openvswitch/ovsdb-server.0.ctl \
   --pidfile=/host/var/run/openvswitch/ovsdb-server.pid \
   --remote=tcp:0.0.0.0:6632 \
   --overwrite-pidfile \
   --detach \
   /host/var/lib/openvswitch/conf.db

ovs-vswitchd \
   --unixctl=/host/var/run/openvswitch/ovs-vswitchd.0.ctl \
   --pidfile=/host/var/run/openvswitch/ovs-vswitchd.pid \
   --overwrite-pidfile \
    tcp:127.0.0.1:6632

the docker log shows:
vswitch-1  | 2024-05-23T22:18:41Z|00001|ovsdb|WARN|/usr/share/openvswitch/vswitch.ovsschema: changed 30 columns in 'Open_vSwitch' database from ephemeral to persistent, including 'status' column in 'Manager' table, because clusters do not support ephemeral columns
vswitch-1  | 2024-05-23T22:18:41Z|00001|raft|INFO|term 1: 800209739 ms timeout expired, starting election
vswitch-1  | 2024-05-23T22:18:41Z|00002|raft|INFO|term 1: elected leader by 1+ of 1 servers
vswitch-1  | 2024-05-23T22:18:41Z|00003|raft|INFO|local server ID is d4dc
vswitch-1  | 2024-05-23T22:18:41Z|00001|ovs_numa|INFO|Discovered 1 CPU cores on NUMA node 0
vswitch-1  | 2024-05-23T22:18:41Z|00002|ovs_numa|INFO|Discovered 1 NUMA nodes and 1 CPU cores
vswitch-1  | 2024-05-23T22:18:41Z|00003|reconnect|INFO|tcp:127.0.0.1:6632: connecting...
vswitch-1  | 2024-05-23T22:18:41Z|00004|reconnect|INFO|tcp:127.0.0.1:6632: connected
vswitch-1  | 2024-05-23T22:18:51Z|00005|memory|INFO|2808 kB peak resident set size after 10.1 seconds

nestat shows that the db is listening.
but the command
ovs-vsctl -v --db=tcp:127.0.0.1:6632 show shows:
2024-05-23T22:32:00Z|00001|vsctl|DBG|Called as ovs-vsctl -v --db=tcp:127.0.0.1:6632 show
2024-05-23T22:32:00Z|00002|reconnect|DBG|tcp:127.0.0.1:6632: entering BACKOFF
2024-05-23T22:32:00Z|00003|reconnect|INFO|tcp:127.0.0.1:6632: connecting...
2024-05-23T22:32:00Z|00004|reconnect|DBG|tcp:127.0.0.1:6632: entering CONNECTING
2024-05-23T22:32:00Z|00005|ovsdb_cs|DBG|tcp:127.0.0.1:6632: SERVER_SCHEMA_REQUESTED -> SERVER_SCHEMA_REQUESTED at lib/ovsdb-cs.c:419
2024-05-23T22:32:00Z|00006|poll_loop|DBG|wakeup due to [POLLOUT] on fd 4 (127.0.0.1:55850<->127.0.0.1:6632) at lib/stream-fd.c:153
2024-05-23T22:32:00Z|00007|reconnect|INFO|tcp:127.0.0.1:6632: connected
2024-05-23T22:32:00Z|00008|reconnect|DBG|tcp:127.0.0.1:6632: entering ACTIVE
2024-05-23T22:32:00Z|00009|jsonrpc|DBG|tcp:127.0.0.1:6632: send request, method="get_schema", params=["_Server"], id=1
2024-05-23T22:32:00Z|00010|ovsdb_cs|DBG|tcp:127.0.0.1:6632: SERVER_SCHEMA_REQUESTED -> SERVER_SCHEMA_REQUESTED at lib/ovsdb-cs.c:419
2024-05-23T22:32:02Z|00011|poll_loop|DBG|wakeup due to [POLLIN] on fd 4 (127.0.0.1:55850<->127.0.0.1:6632) at lib/stream-fd.c:157
2024-05-23T22:32:02Z|00012|jsonrpc|DBG|tcp:127.0.0.1:6632: received request, method="echo", params=[], id="echo"
2024-05-23T22:32:02Z|00013|jsonrpc|DBG|tcp:127.0.0.1:6632: send reply, result=[], id="echo"
2024-05-23T22:32:04Z|00014|poll_loop|DBG|wakeup due to [POLLIN] on fd 4 (127.0.0.1:55850<->127.0.0.1:6632) at lib/stream-fd.c:157 (0% CPU usage)
2024-05-23T22:32:04Z|00015|jsonrpc|DBG|tcp:127.0.0.1:6632: received request, method="echo", params=[], id="echo"
2024-05-23T22:32:04Z|00016|jsonrpc|DBG|tcp:127.0.0.1:6632: send reply, result=[], id="echo"
2024-05-23T22:32:06Z|00017|poll_loop|DBG|wakeup due to [POLLIN] on fd 4 (127.0.0.1:55850<->127.0.0.1:6632) at lib/stream-fd.c:157 (0% CPU usage)
2024-05-23T22:32:06Z|00018|jsonrpc|DBG|tcp:127.0.0.1:6632: received request, method="echo", params=[], id="echo"
2024-05-23T22:32:06Z|00019|jsonrpc|DBG|tcp:127.0.0.1:6632: send reply, result=[], id="echo"

And wait forever in a polling loop. Do I use the wrong schema?
